# Python Error Control Date

Tags: python

I want my program to take user input in form of a date and the control if it is valid. But with the code I have know the program say that it is wrong regardless of what format i give. I don't see the problem with the code:

```
import datetime
def visit_date():
    while True:
        date_visit = input("Enter the date you want to visit the Zoo in YYYY-MM-DD format: ")
        try:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_visit, "%d/%m/%y")
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a valid format\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking the user for a date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` but then trying to parse it according to this format `%d/%m/%y`.

You instead should parse the string in the same way that you requested it, [`%Y-%m-%d`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for format `%d/%m/%y` and asking for `%Y-%m-%d`

```
> date_visit = '2016-11-23'
> datetime.datetime.strptime(date_visit, "%Y-%m-%d")
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 23, 0, 0)
```

Some notes:

- `%Y` : Year in four digits 
  `%y` : year in two digits.
- `%d/%m/%y` translates to *"day of month in one or two digits, `/`, month of year in one or two digits, `/` year in two digits".*
- `%Y-%m-%d` translates to *"four-digit-year, `-`, month-of-year, `-` day-of-month"*

Answer (score 0):

Your prompt asks you to enter in `YYYY-MM-DD`, but your `strptime` is attempting to use the format `%d/%m/%y`. You need to have the formats to match for `strptime` to work

```
import datetime

d = '2016-11-21'
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d")
d = datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 21, 0, 0)

>>> 2016-11-21 00:00:00

d = '11/21/2016'
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%d/%M/%Y")
d = datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 21, 0, 0)

>>> 2016-11-21 00:00:00
```

I personally like to use the `python-dateutil` module for parsing date strings that allows for different formats

> pip install python-dateutil

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

d1 = 'Tuesday, October 21 2003, 12:14 CDT'
d2 = 'Dec. 23rd of 2012 at 12:34pm'
d3 = 'March 4th, 2016'
d4 = '2015-12-09'

print(parse(d1))
>>> 2003-10-21 12:14:00

print(parse(d2))
>>> 2012-12-23 12:34:00

print(parse(d3))
>>> 2016-03-04 00:00:00

print(parse(d4))
>>> 2015-12-09 00:00:00
```